# Post on User Timeline using Facebook Sdk/API

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I want to post a message 'Hello world' with three hashtags #abc #bcd #cde to a users timeline who visits my website and clicks on the share button.
what I have tried :
1)Initially I tried Facebook's javascript SDK but I was not able to do it as publish_actions is now deprecated. So 
2)Secondly I used 'share dialog' to get it done. I was able to post my content there but by default share dialog supports only one Hashtag.
So how can I post multiple Hashtags using share dialog? or is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: No, there is not. You can _suggest_ one hash tag, the user can add more on their own, if they feel like it. This was deliberately limited to one, to prevent spammy developers from trying to abuse the system, and probably also to prevent the generation of too much “uniform” content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefilling the message is not possible and not allowed, it must be user generated. About the hashtag: Only one is possible, you can try adding one in the "quote" parameter - i doubt that it will work though.

Comment: Thanks, adding hashtags to quote can be done but we cannot track it